# Missing required parameters - Laravel

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes

Please, can someone help me.

I tried everything, i can't see a problem, but I am getting this error:

Missing required parameters for [Route: show_categories] [URI: categories{$id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\opg\resources\views\footer\footer_main.blade.php)

I try find answer in SO, but couldn't, probably is noob question, but i don't know what to do next.

my view

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="{{route('show_categories' , [ $categorie = 'voće'])}}">
        <div class="single-service">
            <img src="{{asset('avatars/vegtables.jpg')}}" alt="profile-picture">
            <div class="new">
                <h5>Voće</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

my route

```
Route::get('/categories{$categorie}' , 'Controller@main_categories')->name('show_categories');
```

my controller

```
public function main_categories($categorie){
    return view('categories');
}
```

Thx guys:)

Comment: You are missing a / in your route : categories{$categorie} should be categories/{$categorie} , fix that and check if you still have a problem

Comment: thxxxxxxxxxxx a lot, you saved me!!! now it works, after 2 days haha, thx man!

Comment: Lolz after 2 days ? You could learn a full course from tutorials in these 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

@kopz is right, you are missing a / in your route. Please check his comment. 
One more correction, [ $categorie **=** 'voće'] shoud be [ $categorie **=>** 'voće'].

Comment: hmm thx, but for me it worsk [$categorie = 'voće'], strange...

Answer (score 0):

```
{{route('show_categories' , [ 'categorie' => 'voće'])}}
```